# Phase Noise and Multi-carrier Frequency conversion

Tags: frequency-spectrum, noise, phase, conversion, oscillator

I have a oscillator with a phase noise mask that was represented in dBc at specific offsets from a carrier.

Two options for a multicarrier signal going into a converter, apply the phase noise mask (dBc/Hz) on the total signal power of a multichannel signal (multi-carrier or multiple subcarriers - however you call it)  or the dBc is applied on each individual power of the channels.  dBc/Hz is a meaningless value until its changed into dBW/Hz. My question is whether in a mixer with a multi-channel signal, to apply phase noise is it applied against total signal power or each individual channel/subcarrier/carrier power...

Representing the oscillator with phase noise spectrum as one number, but noting that in reality it covers a bandwidth.

$$Oscillator=Ae^{i \theta } $$

Representing the signal with 3 channels or 3 carriers as below, but noting that in reality each channel covers a bandwidth

$$Signal=e^{i x } + e^{i x }+e^{i x }$$

Then the conversion process is just a multiplication (**but is it really this simple multiplication for multicarrier?**).

$${Signal} \times {Oscillator} =Ae^{i \theta } (e^{i x } + e^{i x }+e^{i x })=Ae^{i (x+ \theta )  } + Ae^{i (x+ \theta )}+Ae^{i (x+ \theta )}$$

This means the same phase noise mask is applied onto each channel or carrier and in this case the phase noise contribution is based on total signal power going into the converter.

It cannot be this simple multiplication because applying the same phase noise mask where it is based on a dBc of total carrier power dramatically increases the EVM from the phase noise in multicarrier situation. Basically 2 carriers gives a 3 dB worse EVM, 4 carriers is 6 dB worse EVM and 8 carriers is 9 dB worse EVM.

But if the phase noise dBc is applied on each individual channel or carrier power then how is that working in real physical world, a signal is multiplied by an LO and that LO has the phase noise thats being imparted onto the signal where that signal is composed of many channels or carriers.

Images for DanBoschen comments:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Local Oscillator is multiplied in the time domain with the received (or transmitted) signal and therefore the spectrums (phase noise spectrum and signal spectrum) will convolve in frequency.

A significant driver of the phase noise mask in the receiver is blocking (jamming) resistance and ability to demodulate two closely spaced channels that have a large power difference. In these cases you can see how the stronger signal will convolve with the phase noise spectrum dumping a lot of noise right over the lower power signal of interest unless the phase noise is low enough.

Comment: but if you have a phase noise mask given in dBc and a multicarrier signal, is this dBc applied on the total signal power or each individual channel power?

Comment: @Villere_DSP the “phase noise mask” is a requirement on your local oscillator. With that you will have an actual local oscillator with a phase noise power spectral density given in dBc/Hz at each offset from the oscillator center frequency. What exactly are you trying to determine? If you want to know the impact of that phase noise on the receiver, the phase noise from the LO convolves with the entire spectrum presented to the mixer RF input.

Comment: Convolves in frequency, not multiplies. If all channels had the same power level, the phase noise would then effect each channel equally. EVM is typically not the driver setting phase noise mask requirements but blocking immunity (anti-jam) for the likely cases of a stronger signal being received together with a weaker signal.

Comment: I am looking at the impact of multiple channels with an oscillator at the same time. I have an oscillator phase noise response that I have converted into time. This multiplies the incoming time domain signal which contains all the channels. So phase noise is imparted onto each channel. But the conversion of phase noise in frequency to time is the issue, it's dBc/Hz at offsets from carrier but is that dBc/Hz on the total signal power (that includes all channels ) or each individual channel, if it's the latter then it's not a straight multiplication of oscillator x Signal ?

Comment: @Villere_DSP As I said, this multiplication in time is convolution in frequency. The phase noise given in  terms of dBc/Hz is already in the frequency domain, not the time domain, so much easier to stay in that domain. To see the effect on each channel consider how that effects the frequency domain spectrum. If you are less familiar with convolution, review what that does (even the simple graphical explanation) and then reread my answer to understand the dominant effect.

Comment: If I get some time in the next couple days I will add a graphic that should remove the confusion

Comment: I understand that phase noise is imparted onto every subcarrier in my signal (i.e. if signal made up of 10 sine waves, phase noise is imparted onto every one). But this is not what I am query, the phase noise mask in dBc/Hz is a meaningless value until its changed into dBW/Hz. My question is on that application, whether in a mixer dBc to dBW is the dBc applied onto total signal power (combined power of all subcarriers), i.e. dBW = Total Signal power - dBc/Hz or is it individual subcarrier power of dBw = Subcarrier power - dBc/Hz? If its a latter, its not multiplication in a mixer.

Comment: @Villere_DSP phase noise is imparted onto every carrier in a dBc quantity; so in dB relative to that carrier.

Comment: An oscillator (sine wave) is mixing the signal to convert the entire block of channels. That oscillator has phase noise on it. The level of that phase noise is unrelated to the signal going through it unless the oscillator (sine wave) power is matched to the total input signal power, which I assume it is. But its not matched (equal) to the each individual channel power because all those channels are superimposed in time to give total signal power. Not possible to do dBc on each channel if the mixing is multiplying the sine wave (oscillator) and the total signal with all channels.

Comment: @Villere_DSP I understand all that well. The mixer (if analog mixer serves to hard limit the LO so the process is indeed phase noise. Other than that the process is multiplication in the time domain which is convolution on the frequency domain. If you convolve the spectrums, the phase noise spectral density (which is in the frequency domain!) will get on every single tone (a modulated signal can be decomposed into individual single tones via Fourier Expansion) in the exact same dBc/Hz relative to each tone. A stronger tone will have stronger absolute power imparted onto it vs a weaker tone

Comment: For the case of a modulated spectrum you simply convolve the two spectrums (LO and received signal)— so for multiple channels that would also apply—- have you tried doing this to see what I am referring to? (Even graphically?)

Comment: First convert phase noise dBc into dBW. Is that conversion on the full signal power (with many channels) or with a single channel? If its the latter, the phase noise mask converted from dBc to dBW (dBc relative to a single channel) is much much smaller than a phase noise that is calculated on total signal power. So if you convolve a phase noise mask calculated from dBc using full signal power and then instead a seperate phase noise using dBc on single channel in the signal you get two different phase noise impacts, the later being much smaller since phase noise power is smaller.

Comment: Further to my comment above, I am not convolving in frequency but converting the phase noise mask into time domain and multiplying that into my multicarrier or multichannel signal. The total phase noise power in time is completely dictated by how the dBc is interpreted and what I question

Comment: The two processes are identical -convolve in freq or multiply in time

Comment: My answer applies; the phase noise in dBc (which is in the frequency domain) convolves with all the signals on the RF. For a single tone on the RF the phase noise would be translated to it at the output relative to the RF tone power (hence dBc)- is there were two tones, each would have the phase noise added to it in frequency centered on each tone and each relative to the power of each tone. A modulated signal can be interpreted as multiple contiguous tones. Multiple modulated carriers just extends this same process further and that process overall is convolution..